# Gorm many-to-many relationship duplicates values

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to set up a many to many relationship in my demo API, between a `Job`, and a list of skills `[]Skill`.

Job Struct

```golang
type Job struct {
    ID          string              `sql:"type:uuid;primary_key;"`
    Title       string              `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Skills      []*skill.Skill      `json:"skills,omitempty"gorm:"many2many:job_skill;"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
}
```

Skill Struct

```golang
type Skill struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

I then use `gorm.DB.AutoMigrate()` to generate the join table automatically.

When I send a `POST` request to my API, the data is created correctly the first time around, and the join table populates as you'd expect.

Example `POST` data

```json
{
    "title": "Senior Python Engineer",      
    "skills": [{"name": "javascript"}, {"name": "python"}]
}
```

But then when I send a `PATCH` request to add a new skill, it duplicates the skill in the skills table and then creates a new record in the join table for the skills that already exist.

Example `PATCH` data

```json
{
    "title": "Lead Engineer",      
    "skills": [{"name": "javascript"}, {"name": "python"}, {"name": "management"}]
}
```

Doing a get request for the data will show the following:

```json
{
    "title": "Lead Engineer",      
    "skills": [{"name": "javascript"}, {"name": "python"}, {"name": "javascript"}, {"name": "python"}, {"name": "management"}]
}
```

I have also tried setting `gorm:"unique"` on the skill struck `Name` but when adding a new Skill it fails as it says the other two already exist, which is good but then won't add the new one.

I am assuming I can only send back new values? Not the entire list?

Some of my Go code for clarity

```golang
func GetJobs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := &[]Job{}
    o := database.DB.Preload("Skills").Find(&j)

    render.JSON(w, r, o)
}

func UpdateJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := &Job{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(j)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    o := database.DB.Model(&j).Where("id = ?", j.ID).Update(&j)

    render.JSON(w, r, o)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two things with gorm associations that I feel aren't adequately conveyed in its documentation which continue to confuse developers.

#### 1) It uses IDs to identify the associated entities

When you Update that list of skills, if they have no IDs in them to gorm they are just new entities to be added. This leads to your duplicated values. Even if you have a `unique` field, if that field isn't the entity's primary key, then gorm will try to create a new record and result in a constraint violation instead.

There are a few ways of dealing with this:

- Making sure the API user must supply an ID for the related entities
- Pulling out of the DB the entity IDs via some other surrogate key that the user does provide, and populating those in your to-save entity. In your case that could be `name` since it's unique.
- Making that surrogate key your primary key (making `name` the `gorm:"primaryKey"` of your `Skill` struct).

#### 2) When Updating, it won't delete existing associations that don't appear in the association slice

When you call Save/Update gorm doesn't delete entities in the *far* side of collection associations. This is a safety feature to avoid accidentally deleting data on a simple Save/Update. You have to be explicit about wanting that behaviour.

To deal with that you can use Association mode to replace the collection as part of your update: `db.Model(&job).Association('Skills').Replace(&job.Skills)`.

Comment: Solid answer thank you! I wasn't sure if that was the case. Ideally, I'd like to dynamically add new skills as they arrive, so I think I'll try the 3rd point in part 1. Failing that I'll try and include an ID and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Eziquel's answer and show what worked for me.

I updated my Skill struct to use the `Name` as the primary key

```golang
type Skill struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty" gorm:"primary_key"`
}
```

I then read some documentation saing to just use `gorm.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&j)` Not sure what it does, but without it, the associations were duplicating or not updating.

```golang
func UpdateJob(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    j := &Job{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(j)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    database.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&j)
    database.DB.Model(&j).Association("Skills").Replace(&j.Skills)

    render.JSON(w, r, &j)
}
```

I dont know what `database.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&j)` does but I saw Jihnzu say to use it in the docs, no further explanation. Using that in combination with the `.Association("Skills").Replace(&j.Skills)` ensure there are no duplicates and that the association updates.

If there was more than one you would do:

```golang
database.DB.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(&j)
database.DB.Model(&j).Association("Skills").Replace(&j.Skills)
database.DB.Model(&j).Association("Locations").Replace(&j.Locations)
```

Comment: The `FullSaveAssociations` option has gorm try to update the associated entity's data as well as the link between the entities (in the case of many-to-many, think of it as either just updating the job_skills join table, or additionally updating the skills table).

Comment: The downside to your code is that the first call will save new connections and changes in the `jobs`, `job_skills` and `skills` tables, then the second call will remove all the `job_skills` for that `job.id`, then readd the new ones. You're duplicating the work.
Try instead `db.Omit("Skills").Updates(&j); db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Model(&j).Association("Skills").Replace(&j.Skills)`.